# where is the implementation of the built-in type: float/double in c++

Tags: c++

I was told that avoiding to do equal or not_equal on float/double type in C++.
But there are [std::equal_to](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to) and [std::not_equal_to](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_equal_to) template functions.
So I am wondering that whether it is reliable to use std::equal_to and std::not_equal_to on float/double in c++?

And I am wondering the **implementation** of the built-in type: float/double in c++, but I couldn't find their source code. Would you please share me their source code too?

Comment: The implementation is internal to your compiler; that's what "built-in" means.  You'd have to read your compiler's source code, if it is open source, but handling of floating point will be spread throughout the compiler, not just in one place.

Comment: Just in case: Is this question specifically related to compiling C++ code while targeting an architecture without floating point support? That would really change how this question is interpreted. If that's the case, you should amend the question with which architecture and which compiler are involved.

Comment: Template code will be distributed in the header files.  It should be easy to look at the implementation of `std::equal_to` and determine exactly what primitives it's using.

Comment: For a plain old value type like a float/double, the implementation of `std::equal_to` is just `==`.  But let's start with the original premise: *I was told that avoiding to do equal or not_equal on float/double type in C++.*  Why were you told that? My guess is because since floating point is never exact, it's generally unreliable to compare if the result of a calculation is exactly a specific value.  So you have to see if the diff between `x` and `y` is "close enough" to warrant being consider "equal".   [Comparing Floating-Point Numbers Is Tricky](https://bitbashing.io/comparing-floats.html)

Comment: It's not true that one should *avoid* comparing floating point for equality/inequality.   What is true is that floating point values are often approximations, and comparing for equality or inequality is testing two values that are both approximations.   Practically - in the lack of understanding of how workings of an algorithm are affected by limited floating point precision - it often works out better to check if a value is in some range (e.g.  `fabs(a-b) < epsilon` instead of `a == b`).

Comment: @Peter unfortunately, this _epsilon_ prescription is often followed blindly: simply using an arbitrary epsilon like `1e-10` for _any_ pair of numbers (e.g. Qt's `qFuzzyCompare`). This is just as stupid as using `a==b` when the equality may be inexact. The link in the comment by **selbie** above discusses this well.

Answer (score 5):

First off, to get that out of the way:

In all implementations of the standard library that I know of, `std::equal_to<float/double>` and `std::not_equal_to<float/double>` simply invoke `==` and `!=` respectively.

That being said:

The advice you got about avoiding the use of `==` and `!=` is generally correct, but it is a bit of an oversimplification. Doing an equality or inequality comparison on floating point values is perfectly legal and has a very well defined meaning. However, it is very rarely the correct thing to do.

There's a few technical reasons behind this, but the gist of it is that different sets of operations that mathematically land on the same number often end up on different floating point values. Just changing the order of a series of additions can lead to a different result. So something as simple as `a + b == c + d` is going to be inherently *unreliable*.

If you want to see just how easy it is to mess things up, compile and run the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::setprecision(17) << 0.1 << "\n";
}
```

Finally, to answer your question as asked: "Where is the implementation?"

In a modern context, on general purpose CPUs that you most likely compile your code for, there is no source code to the implementation for us to point you at. The floating point operations are done directly as cpu-level instructions. If you were dealing with some microcontrollers, old architectures, or other exotic computers, then that would be a different matter.

Comment: Thanks, is it necessary to take their precision/significant digits into consideration?
For example, I could compare two float number directly if their precision within 8 significant digits.

Comment: @zhishan You'd need to write a function that does specifically this, but that's a very hard function to write correctly without being extremely familiar with the intricacies of floating-point behavior.